# Is it possible that black holes have an anti-matter jet?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, antimatter, neutrinos, relativistic-jets

If we can think of the black hole in the center of our galaxy as a group of decaying atoms with neutrinos coming from one side in the jet and anti neutrinos from the other side then would it be possible that a galaxy has 2 sides one which contains more anti matter than the other? In this picture it show a dominant jet over the other. Why? Does anti matter not emit light in the same way matter does? If there is an anti matter jet it would react more with matter? My educated guess would be the anti matter jet would be on the right side of the black hole shown below.

[image]

Comment: Why would we think of our BH like that?

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix It seems logical.

Comment: logic is not sufficient in physics, correct premises are the foundations necessary and this question does not display them. In addition there are no links to the picture .  This is not a science fiction site.

Comment: Any significant anti-matter content would create very bright and hugely distinctive spectral features that no astronomer has ever remarked upon. You do the math.

Comment: @dmckee how massive is the hot spot in the picture and why does the jet  come to an abrupt stop?

Comment: The lack of those spectral features is definitive. It tells us without ambiguity that the mechanism isn't anti-matter. Finding out what the mechanism *is* is harder that ruling out that particular cause. That said, many jet creating structures in the universe show changes in intensity over time (including quite abrupt switching on or off). I was serious when I said that it is worth your time to start working on a structured understanding of the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a beautiful NASA picture with no links or caption provided. Here is a [relevant article](http://www.sciencealert.com/this-supermassive-black-hole-emits-a-beam-of-particles-three-times-longer-than-the-milky-way)

> The scientists composed the image by taking X-ray data (the blue elements in the picture) collected using NASA's Chandra X-ray Observatory and combining it with radio data (seen in red) from Australia's Telescope Compact Array.
>
> They say new data from Chandra indicates there are actually two beams being emitted from the black hole, although one of them, called the counterjet, is harder to make out. This counterjet, which extends to the left of the picture, is comparatively difficult to see due to its motion away from the line of sight to Earth.
>
> The red swirls, called radio lobes, indicate clouds of surrounding gas through which the jet and counterjet extend. On the far right of the image, you can see a bright blue 'hotspot', which the researchers say is caused by shock waves, much like a sonic boom from a supersonic aircraft.
>
> According to the scientists, the emission of X-ray particles *most likely* results from electrons spiralling around magnetic field lines in a process called synchrotron emission. It's not fully understood how it's occurring here, but the researchers think the electrons must be continuously re-accelerated as they move out along the jet.

Italics mine. There is no indication of antimatter annihilation radiation in any of these observations.

Comment: long time no see

Answer (score 2):

The signature of anti-matter annihilation would of course be obvious in that the photon produced would be produced at distinct energies related to the rest mass of the particles. There is of course also no reason why the matter and anti-matter should be separated in the way you suggest.

However, I thought I would tackle the issue of why one jet is more prominent than the other. The prominent jet is orientated towards us (or at least more in our direction than is the counter-jet). Since the particles in the jet are relativistic, the radiation they produce is doppler beamed and boosted. This means that we receive much more radiation from the jet travelling towards us. Indeed the [wikipedia page on relativistic beaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_beaming) uses AGN as an example.